# настройка сервера для socketo.me

Tags: apache, сокет, nginx, websocket, socket.io

на сайте нужно создать сокет подключение.но почему то приложение которое на локалке работает прекрасно никак не хочет работать на удаленном сервере.проверял разные сервера и проблема та же самая вместо 101 switching protocol он выдает 200 ok.мне чтото подсказывает что это проблемы на сервере.точнее надо просто правильно настроить.так вот.сколько я бы не гуглил так ничего и не нашел..может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой...

Comment: кстати, по поводу [уже удалённого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435925/178576): возможно, вам *apache* и не нужен. как верно намекнул там **jfs**, в стандартных библиотеках *python-а* имеется собственная реализация *http-сервера*, она часто используется разработчиками всяких фреймворков. и в такой ситуации «сторонний» *http-сервер* (*apache*, *nginx*, *lighttpd* и т.п.) просто не нужен.

Comment: ну а как на хостинге тогда запускать приложение написанное на чистом питоне?

Comment: я думаю, это зависит от того, как реализовано это приложение. создайте новый вопрос, в котором изложите — что у вас есть, чего хотите добиться, какие шаги вами уже предпринимались.

Answer (score 1):

насколько я знаю, поддержка *websocket*-ов требуется с обеих сторон — и со стороны клиента, и со стороны сервера.

если это так, то, вероятно, ваш локальный *http-сервер* уже имеет эту поддержку, а опробованные вами сторонние серверы либо её не имеют, либо не настроены (корректно) на использование *websocket*-ов.

**дополнение**

apache версии 2.4 и выше [умеет проксировать](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) *websocket-соединения* на *websocket-сервер*. в роли последнего в вашем случае, как я понимаю, выступает некий демон, слушающий, например, порт 8080 на *localhost*-е.

то есть, согласно упомянутой документации, помимо *apache* версии 2.4 (и выше), надо:

1. включить модуль *proxy_wstunnel*. например, для *debian*-основных дистрибутивов, такой командой:

`$ sudo a2enmod proxy_wstunnel`

2. настроить *virtualhost* в *apache* для проксирования к `localhost:8080`, используя примерно такую директиву:

`proxypass "/ws2/" "ws://localhost:8080"`

**отказ от ответственности**

изложенное в дополнении написано по результатам чтения документации и автор не имеет ни опыта работы с *websocket*-ами, ни тем более опыта подобной настройки.

Comment: не настроены скорее всего.просто тогда такой вопрос)как настроить)

Comment: спасибо большое )можно ссылочку на документацию?

Comment: в тексте присутствует. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

Comment: спасибо огромное)могу отписаться о результатах если интересно.

Comment: всё новое интересно. напишите, пожалуйста. я дополню/исправлю ответ, если будут дополнения/коррективы. или напишите собственный ответ.

Comment: @FuadIbrahimov, получилось?

Comment: нет .попробовали настроить.но все равно ничего не получилось.решили пока что отложить но все равно возьмемся попозже уже на второй стадии разработки проекта

Comment: И вот первая стадия разработки проекта закончилась.
Написали приложение на socketo.io (node.js + express) 
Залили сайт на aws amazon .
Работает все прекрасно.меньше возни.никаких настроек апача и нджинкса благодаря ноду